# My Language And Region not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, language, regional-settings

I have a `SP2013` installation with language packs installed. Now I wanted to change my preferred language so SharePoint uses that instead of the default language of my browser settings. When I click "My Settings" and then "My Language And Region", the page just refreshes and nothing seems to happen.

On the internet I found the link to the page, when I use that; the correct page opens, but saving the changes results in an error. So apparently something is wrong there, I just don't know what. Where could this setting be located? I thought of `User Profile`, but isn't the same functionality in `Foundation` as well (which lacks the User Profile Service)?

Comment: I have the same issue on a tenant site. Don't know what's causing it to simply refresh instead of showing the settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I had some weird parameters in the url of my `muisetng.aspx` page. Try going there straight from the site collection by adding `/_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx` to the sharepoint host url.

I guess the minimum download strategy caused some issues which resulted in the postback not getting through.